# PHP - unlink not properly working

Tags: php, cookies, unlink

I'm trying to delete cookie files with the `unlink()` function and it's not working properly

I tried this code (found on php.net)

```
<?php array_map('unlink', glob("some/dir/*.txt")); ?>
```

But it do not delete the last created file...

Comment: Does your webserver user have proper permissions?

Comment: Does `var_dump(glob("some/dir/*.txt"));` returns any files?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky : Yes :)

Comment: @emreaydin149 : Yes :)

Comment: Can you post some outputted values?

Comment: @emreaydin149 :
before unlink : array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "CUR76B.tmp" }
after unlink : array(0) { } (the file is still in the folder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are any number of reasons your code may be failing on one file but not the others.  It doesn't appear to be a logic error, but the first thing I would do is try to rewrite this as a loop rather than using `array_map()`.

Then I would check for an error after each call to `unlink()` if it returns `FALSE`: `if (!(unlink($file)) print_r(error_get_last());` and see what the system tells you about what's going on.

Comment: I've tried with a "for" loop before trying with array_map and every unlink call returns "true"
I also tried by calling another file to delete my cookies and it worked...

Comment: Then I would print out each file name as it gets unlinked and confirm that the one that remains is in the list of ones that it says successfully unlinked.  If so, then check the file creation date to make sure it wasn't re-created after you unlinked it.

Comment: `foreach (glob("*.tmp") as $cookie)
{
 if(unlink($cookie))
 {
  echo "$cookie deleted<br/>";
 }
 else
 {
  echo "$cookie not deleted<br/>";
 }
}`
CUR771.tmp deleted
CUR772.tmp deleted
CUR773.tmp deleted (still in folder)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not %100 sure but maybe you have to include path:

```
<?php
    foreach(glob("some/dir/*.tmp") as $file)
    {
        unlink("some/dir/".$file);
    }
```